# Finding d in RSA encryption without extended euclid algorithm

Tags: assembly, rsa, public-key-encryption, pic, number-theory

I am trying to implement RSA in a PIC16 micro-controller using assembly!
I wrote a math library that can perform addition,subtraction, multiplication and modular exponentiation (all unsigned).

but now I am stuck with the last step that is finding "d" which satisfies:
d*e = 1 (mod phi(n)) 
I want to avoid implementing the extended Euclid algorithm which is a bit complicated and needs signed operations.

I tried calculating it with Euler's theorem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse#Using_Euler.27s_theorem 
but then I need to find phi(phi(n) which is a complicated process unless p and q are safe primes.

The only option I am left with 
is to loop through d=(KN+1)/e while changing k until (KN+1) mod e = 0 
so my question now is: is this last formula the only other option for calculating d?
(if not) what are other options?
and what are the limits of K ?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the *binary* extended Euclidean algorithm. The algorithm can be found in the [Handbook of Applied Cryptography - Chapter 14.4.3](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/about/chap14.pdf). It only requires multiple-precision additions, subtractions, and shifts. The note: 14.64 describes how to optimize the algorithm to obtain the multiplicative inverse - `(d)` in this case.

It's typical to chose a relatively small prime with a low Hamming weight for `(e)`, like `(65537)`. Since `gcd(65537, phi(n)) = 1`, the multiplicative inverse will always exist.